# What are floors made of?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

When I try to construct a floor in DF, it says that there is no material.  What material do I need?

Comment: You select the material to make the floor out of during the designation process.

Comment: Do you have (non-forbidden) rocks or logs lying around first?

Comment: Since you mention specifically that you're trying to build floors, you probably have pathing issues. Dwarves can't build "ceilings", so they need to be able to walk to the top of wherever you want to build. Check your stairways and/or ramps; they're probably disconnected.

Comment: I don't think you can make a floor out of Lava, but you could make the floor out of Obsidian by completely excavating the area, filling it with lava and water, and then mining out everything but the floor. Of course, this will probably lead to Fun.

Comment: @Alex: No, the floor is *under* the lava. And so is the lever to turn off the magma pumps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Floors, like all [constructions](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2014:Construction), can be made from a variety of materials:

- stone, resulted from mining through rock
- blocks,made from stones (4 blocks result from one boulder), wood (only one, so pretty pointless), metal or glass.
- logs, resulted from cutting trees
- bars, resulted from... well a lot of places: metal bars from smelting ore, ash bars from burning logs, soap bars are made in a workshop from lye and tallow... and due to game limitations, all of these can be used for building.

Plus, dwarfs need a path to the future construction; if they can't get to it, they can't build it, and the game wisely, or annoyingly in some cases, prevents you from designating.

Comment: Building megastructures out of soap is the opposite of limitation.

Comment: @user1337 It's still a limitation of the game that it can't tell the difference between an ash bar and a gold ingot. And in the mean time, we players exploit the hell out of it.